# Element in OrCAD

Tags: switches, orcad

[image: electric scheme]
I want to model electric scheme in OrCAD from an image and I stuck on element K1 (surrounded by the red rectangle). What is this element, why do we need it, and can I find it in standard OrCAD library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

K1 is a relay coil. The coil is the black rectangle and the contacts are on the right (K1.3=NO/K1.2=COM/K1.1=NC). VD2 is the flyback or catch diode.

K is usually used for relay names on schematics.

Comment: Is there any library with this element?

Comment: There are relays in Orcad, or you can download a specific one, I usually use [SnapEDA](http://www.snapeda.com).

Comment: They might look differently.

Comment: Right, there are a number of different ways to represent a relay on a schematic, but how they work is the same (as long as it has same electrical characteristics).